# Python asyncio aiohttp request data encoding

Tags: python, request, urlencode, aiohttp

I'm using python's aiohttp basic request module to make requests. My request is `base64` encoded string and request body looks like:

```
body = {'request': 'eyJhYmMiOiJ4eXoifQ=='}
```

Here is the code for sending request:

```
response = yield from request(method='POST', url=url, allow_redirects=False, headers=headers, data=body)
```

The problem here is, this is getting received at the other end as:

```
{'request': 'eyJhYmMiOiJ4eXoifQ%3D%3D'}
```

which I believe is the `url-encoded` version of my request body.

How can I avoid this and send request as it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove content type from header if you are sending

Answer (score 3):

Use `json` parameter. An example from [documentation](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client.html#json-request):

```
async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    async with session.post(url, json={'test': 'object'})
```

Answer (score 0):

its sad @Svetlov answer is not selected. He is the Aiohttp core developer